# Export function from a component in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to export a function from a Vue.js component, so that a custom button can call it.

This is the `btn.vue` component:

```html
<template>
  <button @click="externalFunction()" class="btn">
    <slot></slot>
  </button>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'btn',
  }
</script>
```

This is the main page:

```html
<template>
  <btn>
    Button
  </btn>
</template>

<script>
  import btn from '@/components/btn.vue'
  
  export default {
    name: 'page',
    components: {
      btn
    },
    methods: {
      externalFunction () {
        // this is the function
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

How can I execute "`externalFunction`" using the `btn` component?

Comment: emit that the button was clicked `@click="$emit('click')"` then listen on the component like normal `<btn @click="externalFunction">`, here is an example if you want to use named slots https://playcode.io/826186/ note the *Submit From Parent* part

Comment: do you see any error. Also make sure the `externalFunction` is defined under `methods` inside `btn.vue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [Lawrence Cherone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661872/lawrence-cherone) to solve my problem, there is the solution:
`brn.vue` component:

```
<button @click="$emit('click')"></button>
```

The main page

```
<btn @click="myFunction()"></btn>
```